# How to create readonly collection in fastutil?

Tags: java, collections, unmodifiable, fastutil

In standard library we have methods like [`Collections#unmodifiableCollection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection))

Can't find the same for types collections in fastutil. Please hint!

Answer (score 0):

`IntSets.unmodifiable()` is the answer. Sorry javadoc site is offline now.